# How to make clickable and zoomable slider in a fragment?

Tags: android, jquery, android-studio, android-fragments, slider

Hello i want to make clickable and also zoomable viewpager in a fragment. When i click viewpager i want to start a activity and when i doubletap to viewpager i want to make zoom.I tried few things but failed.

Here is my fragment.java

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment  {
private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);


    mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    file_maps.put("img1",R.drawable.img_1);
    file_maps.put("img2",R.drawable.img_2);


    for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getContext());
        // initialize a SliderLayout
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

        mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
    mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.ZoomOutSlide);
    mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
    return view;
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public Adapter (Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return SliderLayout.Transformer.values().length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return SliderLayout.Transformer.values()[position].toString();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView t = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item,null);
    t.setText(getItem(position).toString());
    return t;
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly did you try? to avoid wasting respondents' time

Comment: i followed this tutorial [link]( https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-image-slider-using-androidimageslider-library-tutorial/) i made imageslider perfectly working but now i want to add zoom option to this but i dont know how

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: it is griwview i dont want griview and i am confused how can i change it.